# Box v2 API - "Remember login" checkbox

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, box-api

To the Box SDK team:

I'm using the iOS version of the BoxSDK. When I present the `BoxAuthorizationViewController` login controller, there is a checkbox labeled "Remember login".

It doesn't seem to do anything. I get the same results whether I leave it checked or not. And the iOS API to the Box SDK doesn't provide any access to whether it is checked or not.

In my iOS app I'd like to know whether the user checked this or not. If they have it checked then I want to store the refresh token in the keychain so the user doesn't need to login again. But if the user unchecks this on the login screen, I need to know this so I don't store the token in the keychain and my app can ensure the user is shown the login screen again on the next access.

What is this "Remember login" checkbox supposed to do in the context of an iOS app?

Can the API be updated so when the `BoxOAuth2SessionDidBecomeAuthenticatedNotification` notification is sent, the state of the checkbox is part of the notification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New OAuth2 screens just went live that should fix this problem:

https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=https://your-token-generator.com

Comment: Thanks for resolving this issue.